# Access Azure SQL from Azure WebApp via Managed Identity and Private EndPoint

Tags: azure, azure-web-app-service, azure-sql-database, azure-virtual-network

I have an AspNetCore3.1 app hosted on Linux Azure WebApp. I have enabled Private Endpoint on the same. All works like a charm.
Now to add DB interaction, I have enabled system assigned Managed Identity(MI) for the web app and added that as contained user to my Azure SQL PaaS. However, I'm getting errors while DB connection:

> Connection was denied since Deny Public Network Access is set to Yes
> (https://learn.microsoft.com/azure/azure-sql/database/connectivity-settings#deny-public-network-access).
> To connect to this server, use the Private Endpoint from inside your
> virtual network
> (https://learn.microsoft.com/azure/sql-database/sql-database-private-endpoint-overview#how-to-set-up-private-link-for-azure-sql-database).
> at
> Microsoft.Data.ProviderBase.DbConnectionPool.CheckPoolBlockingPeriod(Exception
> e)

There is Private Endpoint configured for SQL DB too. This one is in different subnet but same VNet as webapp's private endpoint is in.

-Update: I have verified that the error is still thrown even if I remove Private Endpoint from webApp.

What am I missng here?

Answer (score 5):

The error message indicates that you are trying to access the SQL server over the public network from your web app. You need to restrict the outgoing traffic from the web app in a VNet then you can use a private endpoint for your SQL server. Read [using Private Endpoints for Azure Web App](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/app-service/networking/private-endpoint#conceptual-overview).

> Private Endpoint is only used for incoming flows to your Web App.
> Outgoing flows will not use this Private Endpoint, but you can inject
> outgoing flows to your network in a different subnet through the VNet
> integration feature.

When you add an private endpoint connection in your SQL server, you will see there are Service endpoints for `Microsoft.Sql` and Private endpoints in the VNet that you create a private endpoint for your SQL server.

To access the Azure web app to SQL server within a private network over a private link. You need to enable [VNet Integration for your web app](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/app-service/web-sites-integrate-with-vnet#regional-vnet-integration) in another empty subnet in the same VNet. By default, your app won't work with Azure DNS Private Zones. To work with Azure DNS Private Zones you need to add the following app settings:

```
WEBSITE_DNS_SERVER with value 168.63.129.16
WEBSITE_VNET_ROUTE_ALL with value 1
```

### **Test result** in native Windows apps

From web app to SQL db with the two above app settings `WEBSITE_DNS_SERVER` and  `WEBSITE_VNET_ROUTE_ALL` condigured, it resolves to a private IP address.

[image]

From web app to SQL db with the app settings `WEBSITE_DNS_SERVER` with value `168.63.129.16` by using private DNS zone and without `WEBSITE_VNET_ROUTE_ALL` condigured. It resolves to public IP address.

[image]

Comment: All this works as expected on Windows web app however if I chose Linux to host my app, it fails not even loads. Kudu console is not returning any results. I tried nameresolver which was not found. Tcpping is not returning any response.

Comment: yes the test command doesnot work in linux web app but vnet integration does the same senario. You can deploy a windows test vm in the same vnet to verify it.

Comment: Hi, please note that you can not mix the Windows web apps and Linux web apps in the same app service plan. If you chose Linux to host your app, you need to deploy it in another service plan and integrated its app into a new subnet. The regional vnet integration feature is fully supported for both Windows and Linux apps, including custom containers. All of the behaviors act the same between Windows apps and Linux apps. One exception, `WEBSITE_VNET_ROUTE_ALL` is currently not supported in Windows containers.

Comment: I tried with 2 new App service plans and 2 seperate subnets for vnet integration but results are different. Same app with Windows WebApp works without issues. Another one with Linux web app fails to even start my app after vnet integration.

Comment: When you said the same app with windows web app works without issue, Another one with Linux web app fails. Could you verify that the web app can start or work well before VNet integration? It looks like a problem with the web app itself. Also, you should remove the private endpoint on the web app UI(this restricts the public access to your Web App) when you access this web app over the Internet.

Comment: Yes Linux webapp works until I enable Vnet integration. PEP is not enabled on this web app.

Comment: Looks like I need to open a support ticket with Microsoft. Because I'm out of ideas here. Thanks again for your help.

Comment: THANK YOU for posting this answer, it helped a lot.  FWIW I had a problem with my Private DNS Zones whereby Azure was creating them and adding endpoint registrations but was not linking it to the VNet.  So if you are running into resolution problem, make sure the Private DNS Zone has a link to the VNet because Azure does not add these automatically it seems.